# Insert video to HTML

Tags: asp.net, html

I trying to insert video at `HTML`, so I have video URL, width and height. Is it enough for building correct object? I found how to build object for .SWF, but how to build any other formats?

P.S. I don't have video file on server, I'm using external video URL as a source.

Here is my code for .SWF format:

```
private string GetVideoType(string filename, out string formatHtml)
        {
            string videoType = formatHtml = "";

            if (filename.EndsWith(".swf"))
            {
                videoType = "swf";
                formatHtml = @"
                <object width='{0}' height='{1}' data='{2}' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
                    <param name='src' value='{2}'></param>
                    <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'></param>
                    <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'></param>
                    <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'></param>
                    <param name='pluginspage' value='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'></param>
                    <param name='wmode' value='window'></param>
                    <param name='flashvars' value='playerForm=LVPPlayer&mediaId=a46002fd61264c09a36a90ca66c994cb'></param>
                </object>";
            }
            else if (filename.EndsWith(".flv"))
            {
                videoType = "flv";
                formatHtml = "???"
            }
            else if (filename.EndsWith(".mp4"))
            {
                videoType = "mp4";
                formatHtml = "???"
            }
            else if (filename.EndsWith(".wmv"))
            {
                videoType = "wmv";
                formatHtml = "???"
            }

            return videoType;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirements, but it might be worth it if you look at HTML5 Video tag. Here are some details here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Html5 video is a good idea, but not all browsers support each of these formats. For example Firefox will not play MP4...

Comment: Yes, you are right. To work around it, you must have at least 2 formats for each video, OGG and MP3 (If I remember right, those two formats will be suitable for all major browsers).

You stated you are not hosting your vids, so maybe this will not work, but if you do host them, then you need one format, and there are codecs that you can programatically use to convert one format to the other and host both of them.

Of course, at one point in futures, all browsers will support all video types, and until then, you have to be creative with your solutions.

Comment: .swf is Adobe's vidoe. The user should have the player for it, so if you set it as your source, and test it to work on your own test browsers (all major 5 I would say), then the user should have no problem playing them. If they do not have Adobe player, then they will be directed to download it, once they do, then you have your video. HTML5 will kill SWF, but this will take time to happen, so your solution for now is what you are attempting.

Comment: yeah, but the issue is that I don't have this video in different formats, I only have URL to mp4 (for example) file. And how to make play it at all browsers?

Comment: OK, let me get this straight, you are saying you have links to different videos, some of those videos are SWF, some are MP4, some are OGG. And all those links are external. What you want to do is embed those videos in your webpages and have them play on all browsers. Did I get this right?

Comment: Hmm, this is a bit of a challange. Try this: First, Check if the source is SWF; if so, then just display it and the user will deal with downloading Adobe player. Then check the type of the file, if is it MP4 then check if the source also has an OGG file somewhere; if so, then just use HTML5. Also, if the source is OGG, check if there is MP4 on ther server; if so, then use HTML5 again. If there is only one source (either MP4 or OGG); then download the vid, do your conversion, and save a local copy of either both copies or only the only new one (linking to the other).

Answer (score 0):

maybe should take a look at the HTML5  tag.

Code Here:

```
<video src="/video/example.ogg" width="320" height="240" controls>
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the HTML5 video element.</p>
</video>
```

Comment: Html5 video is a good idea, but not all browsers support each of these formats. For example Firefox will not play MP4...

Answer (score 0):

or take a look at this player: http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

it works really well.

you can use mp4 video files and they are visible in firefox

html code:

```
<div id="q1">Loading the player ...</div>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("q1").setup({
        flashplayer: "/public/javascript/jwp/player.swf",
        file: "/videos/q1.mp4",
        image: "/videos/q1.jpg",
        height: 349,
        width: 620
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sound interesting, and how to use it? Is it also build HTML object? I could not find example on this site....

Comment: Its interesting, but not exactly what I want... I want to store HTML content of video, to be able show it in other places of my application. Can we use only HTML layout for building videos using this player?